# Which symbol can be used to refer to identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

$I$ is commenly used as a notation of identity matrix. I am wondering is there any notation else for identity matrix?

Comment: $\text{Id}$ is also common.

Comment: I have seen the use of $I_d$ to denote a $d\times d$ identity matrix. As an added comment to JimmyK4542's, you may also see the more explicit notation $\operatorname{id}_V$ where $V$ is the relevant vector space.

Comment: In some contexts, I have also seen a doublestrike $1$, similar to the difference between $N$ and $\mathbb N$, in order to emphasize that it is the compositional identity.  The fact that I am unable to type it in mathjax right away however should imply something about how uncommon that notation is though.

Comment: I use \mathds{1} to get the double strike 1 (aaah so lovely) but the dsfont package isn't a default. Picked it up from some random lecture notes from someone at EPFL and liked it.

Comment: More rarely now, but at some point $E$ was used for the identity.

Comment: @copper.hat: $E$ is sometimes used in German (*Einheitsmatrix*), and also in my native Swedish (*enhetsmatris*).

Comment: @HansLundmark: Thanks, that makes sense!

Comment: @copper.hat that is cool~ definitely what i want :)

Comment: $1\, , \,\mathbb{1}\, , \,\mathbf{1}\, , \,\operatorname{I}\, , \, \mathbb{I}\, , \,\mathbf{I}\, , \,\operatorname{Id}\, , \,\operatorname{id}$ and anyone of these could be equipped with an index $n$ or not.

Answer (score 3):

**[From Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)**:

---

It is denoted by $I_n$, or simply by $I$ if the size is immaterial or can be trivially determined by the context. (In some fields, such as quantum mechanics, the identity matrix is denoted by a boldface one, **1**; otherwise it is identical to $I$.)

---

It can also be written using the [Kronecker delta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) notation:

$$(I_{n})_{ij}=\delta _{ij}.$$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a "double one" like this: $\mathbb{1}$. To write it in LaTeX, you can import the package `dsfont` and then use `\mathds{1}`. You can also import `bbold` and then use `\mathbb{1}`, but this will change the appearance of your other `\mathbb` commands.

Answer (score 1):

$I_n$

$I_m$

$I_n = diag(1,1,1,1\cdots,1)$

$(I_n)_{ij} =\delta_{ij}$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the notation $\mathbb{I}$ written using this code `\mathbb{I}`